# The up navigation arrow is not showing up in the app bar

Tags: android, xml

I'm writing my first app.  I've done some practicals with Google Codelabs and learned to add an up navigation arrow to the app bar.  When I try it with my app the navigation arrow is not anywhere.

The only difference between the practical and my code is the theme, which I've tried to change but the app stops when I do because I am not using an AppCompat theme which I have not learned yet.  But I do not know if the theme is the problem.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Lists"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_lists"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.fourwomendev.simplyneatlist.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I expect a left pointing arrow to the left of the title of the activity Lists on the app bar, but there is not one.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing my first app. I've done some practicals with Google
>   Codelabs and learned to add an up navigation arrow to the app bar.
>   When I try it with my app the navigation arrow is not anywhere.

Because you are not using any `Actionbar` in your activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Lists"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_lists"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" //<-----no actionbar is 
    specified
   > 
   .......
</activity>
```

Use one actionbar to get the left arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to work with errors from changing the theme I realized that the basic activity I chose when creating this activity is created with a toolbar in Java. So I took out the code that created the toolbar and the reference to the theme in XML and my up navigation arrow appeared.